# How can I sign bitcoin transaction offline use bitcoinj and some other c programs

Tags: bitcoinj, trezor

We are want to do a device like trezor or ledger , and we try to sign transaction in the offline device which use c program like trezor , first our online app get utxos and get the TansactionInput , but we do not know how to change the inputs to the pre sign hash , and also the sign with c program . is there anybody had to do like this and could you give us some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Look at packages like [python-trezor](https://github.com/trezor/python-trezor).  They have a tool in it called `trezorctl` that allows offline TXN creation.  Technically you need to need to get TX data from a server, but it is a small amount of data, and easy to spoof in SW if proof-of-concept bears out.

Here's an example of a [simple_trezor_txn-py](https://gist.github.com/brianddk/e57a4ef04e2a7fc24da29a4baf91b343#file-simple_trezor_txn-py) script in 50 lines that does most of what you need.